# Play youtube videos in fullscreen auto

Tags: objective-c, ipad, youtube

I am trying to play a youtube video using youtube embedded player in my ipad app. I want that as soon as the user clicks on the video thumbnail the video automatically should be loaded fullscreen on switching to landscape mode in ipad. Currently the user has to click the fullscreen button to play the video in fullscreen mode.
I want the same effect that is seen when we play the video using the default youtube app that comes with ipad.

This is the code that I am using to play you tube video on ipad.

```
embedHTML = @"<object width=\"640\" height=\"390\">
<param name=\"movie\"value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/IYX_Ql-3U10&fs=1\">
<param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param>
<param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\"></param>
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/youtube_video_id&fs=1\" 
type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" position=\"fixed\" 
allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowScriptAccess=\"always\"
 width=\"640\" height=\"390\"></embed></object>";
```

And if this is not possible does anybody know if there is a reason or documentation supporting this decision.

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question, if so could you please share it. I am too trying to autoplay a youtube video from my app.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, it's not allowed :)

Comment: You mean to say that we cannot have the same effect in our ipad app that we see when we play a youtube video on ipad. Please post some documentation url that confirms your answer.

Comment: If this is not possible then how does the youtube app that comes with ipad enables this feature.

Comment: So they also must have adopted some method for this isn't it.

Comment: yea the "method" is a private API and is not documented anywhere so there is no sure way of knowing how they do it.

Comment: @shruti the youtube app is not the same kind of app as you are building. try submitting your cv to apple and/or google.

Comment: What do you mean it's not allowed to play fullscreen youtube video? You can do it with any Android devices (phone or tablet), but you set it's not allowed with iPad? What is wrong with this world?

Comment: So fullscreen mode only works with iPhone (Youtube iframe API + WebView)...

Comment: Actually it's possible to go fullscreen youtube on iPad: `let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false`

Answer (score 4):

I was able to access this functionality from a subview titled *FigPluginView* within the youtube player's webview, using the iOS youtube helper [iOS-youtube-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper).
[FigPluginView class dump reference](https://github.com/limneos/classdump-dyld/blob/master/iphoneheaders/iOS7.0.3/System/Library/Internet%20Plug-Ins/QuickTime%20Plugin.webplugin/FigPluginView.h)

Create a custom UIView class header that exposes the following method:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 
@interface WMFigPluginView : NSObject

-(void)scriptEnterFullScreen;

@end
```

Import the custom FigPluginView and YouTube player to the ViewController interface()

```
    #import <youtube-ios-player-helper/YTPlayerView.h>
    #import "WMFigPluginView.h"

    @property(nonatomic, strong) YTPlayerView *playerView;
```

Use the following methods to init the youtube player, monitor state change, find and call the fullscreen script within the FigPluginView.

```
- (void)presentYoutubeVideo {
    if ([self.view.subviews containsObject:_playerView]){
        [_playerView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    CGRect playerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    _playerView = [[YTPlayerView alloc]initWithFrame:playerFrame];
    _playerView.delegate = self;
    [_playerView.webView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback: NO];
    [self.view addSubview:_playerView];
    [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"YouTubeVideoID" playerVars:@{@"showinfo":@0,@"modestbranding":@1,@"autoplay":@1,@"playsinline":@0}];
}

-(void)playerViewDidBecomeReady:(YTPlayerView *)playerView {
    [_playerView playVideo];
}

-(void)playerView:(YTPlayerView *)playerView didChangeToState:(YTPlayerState)state {
    //stop activity indicator
    if (state == kYTPlayerStateBuffering) {
        //start activity indicator
    }
    if (state == kYTPlayerStatePlaying) {
        WMFigPluginView *figPluginView = (WMFigPluginView*)[self findFigPluginView:_playerView.webView];
        [figPluginView scriptEnterFullScreen];
    }
}

- (UIView *)findFigPluginView:(UIView *)view {
    for (__unsafe_unretained UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasSuffix:@"FigPluginView"]) {
            return subview;
        } else if (subview.subviews.count > 0) {
            return [self findFigPluginView:subview];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: link of FigPluginView class dump reference is broken, didn't see repository related to it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no straightforward solution. If my client will want it (I will know in a few days :-)) I will probably try to open new controller with webview that covers entire screen and then autoplay it like in this post:
[How to make YouTube video starts to play automatically inside UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513842/how-to-make-youtube-video-starts-to-play-automatically-inside-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the authors of the other answers, it is completely possible to do this using UIWebViews in iOS AND without leveraging private APIs. Here's a pretty simple method to do so.

```
- (void)playYoutubeVideo:(NSString *)videoId {
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    webView.center = self.view.center; //Technically not needed, I've found it looks better with this added (when the video is done playing it looks better while being minimized)
    webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'768', height:'1024', videoId:'%@', events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>", videoId];

   [webView loadHTMLString:youTubeVideoHTML baseURL: [NSBundle mainBundle].bundleURL];
}
```

The crux of this implementation is using a UIWebView with a frame of CGRectZero together with custom HTML/Javascript that handles autoplaying the video. With the UIWebView with the CGRectZero frame, the user doesn't see any annoying intermediate page before the video is autoplayed, and the HTML/Javascript does the heavy lifting involved with getting the page to autoplay the video.

There's a slight delay before the video is presented. I haven't found a way to eliminate this couple second delay unfortunately.