# Play YouTube videos in fullscreen by default

Tags: objective-c, ios, youtube

Is there a way to play YouTube videos in fullscreen by default without the need of clicking the fullscreen button?

And if not, then how does the YouTube app that comes with iPad implement this feature?

Please suggest some ways.  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should probably mention your platform in the tags.

Comment: what was wrong with the answer you got on your other posting of the same question?  Possible duplicate of [Play youtube videos in fullscreen auto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345033/play-youtube-videos-in-fullscreen-auto)

Comment: @Dave DeLong  Because my client is saying that there must be some method for it if the youtube app can do so. Thats why I want to know that if not with embedded code concept then is there some other way with which this feature can be possible.

Comment: The YouTube app probably uses a private API.  If you can find out what that API is, so can you, but your API will not get accepted for the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's not allowed :)