# Play youtube video in fullscreen on button click on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I want to play a youtube video in fullscreen on click of a button. I currently have the following `iframe`:

```
<div class="youtube-trailer">
    <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/whatever" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

On Safari Mobile, specifically, when a press the Play button the video launches in full screen which is the desired behavior. This is fine. I don't want the `iframe` displayed on the page though. I just want a button that will open the video in fullscreen using the native video player. i.e. i don't want to create an overly-elaborate lightbox to house the video.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what's the content of your youtube-trailer class?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345033/play-youtube-videos-in-fullscreen-auto?rq=1) question? I'm not sure if it can help.

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevance of my `youtube-trailer` class but it's `.youtube-trailer {
 position: relative;
 margin:20px 10px;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
 padding-top: 25px;
 height: 0;
}`.

Comment: @nicholaschris That question appears to relate directly to Obj-C and is almost 2 and a half years old

Comment: html5 videos default to full screen on ios from iphone.

Comment: @BingeBoy So can you tell me how do I trigger the playing of the video using another button (i.e. not the default YouTube play button). As I said I'm happy with the video being played in fullscreen - it's what i want

Comment: I just made a test page and it loaded video in fullscreen:
    <html>
     <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tA2EJrS9wxc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
       </html>

Comment: @BingeBoy not defaults to - is restricted only to. iPad video can be 'in-page' but even iPhone 6 restricts all HTML 5 video to fullscreen.

Comment: @Simon_Weavery yes is this a specific question for ipads? I replied years ago...

Answer (score 10):

The standard youtube video link format is:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lv-sY_z8MNs
```

You can link directly to the full screen video (without opening a new window) by adding "_popup" after "watch" in the URL:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=Lv-sY_z8MNs
```

This should work for both mobile and desktop browsers. Naturally, if you did end up wanting to open your link in a new page, simply add "target="_blank" to your opening anchor tag.